# Элементы списка по высоте самого высокого блока

Tags: html, css

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo-bar {
  
  background: green;
}

.logo-bar .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 220px;
}

.punkts ul li {
  background: red;
}

.line {
  background-color: violet;
}

.line .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section class="logo-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block1">2</div>
    <div class="punkts">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

На меcте block1 будет стоять логотип с `w100% h-auto` который соответственно будет адаптивно уменьшаться. Вопрос: как не зависимо от размера логотипа(хоть 3000px) растягивать li по высоте на 100% по logo-bar (то есть по высоте самого высокого блока в контейнере)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;  
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
}

.logo-bar {  
  background: green;
}

.logo-bar .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  /*Не центрируем все flex-элементы*/
}

.logo {
  width: 220px;
  align-self:center;
  /*Центрируем только лого*/
}
.punkts ul{
  min-height:100%;
  /*растянуть список на высоту родителя и флексом растянуть его потомков*/
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
  margin:0;
}
.punkts ul li {
  background: red;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="logo-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo"><img src="http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_336389.png"/></div>
    <div class="punkts">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).load(function () {
    var max_col_height = 0;
    $('.punkts li').each(function () {
        if ($(this).height() > max_col_height) {
            max_col_height = $('.logo-bar').height();
        }
    });
    $('.punkts li').height(max_col_height);
});
```

```css
.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0 12px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style: none;
}

.logo-bar {
  
  background: green;
}

.logo-bar .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo {
  width: 220px;
}

.punkts ul li {
  background: red;
}

.line {
  background-color: violet;
}

.line .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.block1 {
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="logo-bar">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block1">2</div>
    <div class="punkts">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Должно помочь.

Comment: Спасибо. А без js нельзя?